# Annotation validation using ModelDriven in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts2, model-driven

I'm trying to use `ModelDriven` approach + validation on the server side using annotations. But it seems like annotations simply don't work. I have a simple `User` class with `name`, `surname`, `email`, etc:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Validation
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String country;
    private String aboutYou;
    private Boolean mailingList;
    ...
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    @RequiredStringValidator(message = "User Name field is empty.")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_GENDER")
    @RequiredStringValidator(message = "User Gender field is empty.")
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
...
}
```

I use  `@RequiredStringValidator` for validation on `gender` and `name` fields.

My `UserAction` class that processes requests is:

```
@Validation
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6659925652584240539L;

    private User user = new User();
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    private UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl();

    @VisitorFieldValidator(message = "", appendPrefix = false)
    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }

    /**

     * To save or update user.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    @VisitorFieldValidator(message = "", appendPrefix = false)
    public String saveOrUpdate() {
        userDAO.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * To list all users.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String list() {
        userList = userDAO.listUser();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @VisitorFieldValidator(message = "", appendPrefix = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    ...
}
```

I use `@VisitorFieldValidator(message = "", appendPrefix = false)` because I've read that it is needed in case with `ModelDriven` approach.

**My `struts.xml` is:**

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
        <action name="saveOrUpdateUser" method="saveOrUpdate" class="com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">listUser</result>
            <result name="input">/register.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.tutorials4u.web.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/register.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/register.jsp</result>
        </action>
</struts>
```

I've read that it's needed to define `<result name="input">` for validation.

Here is my `register.jsp` in which fields that must be validated are defined:

```
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser" method = "POST" validate="true">
    <s:actionerror/>
    <s:fielderror />
    <s:push value="user">
        <s:hidden name="id" />
        <s:textfield name="name" label="User Name" />
        <s:radio name="gender" label="Gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" />
        <s:select name="country" list="{'India','USA','UK'}" headerKey=""
                  headerValue="Select" label="Select a country" />
        <s:textarea name="aboutYou" label="About You" />
        <s:checkbox name="mailingList"
                    label="Would you like to join our mailing list?" />
        <s:submit />
    </s:push>
</s:form>
```

**My `web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <description>struts2</description>
    <display-name>struts2</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And the problem is that all this don't work. I still fighting against this for 4 hours and the only idea in my head tells me that it is easier to make `my_own_bicycle` validation instead of using such *convenient* solution for validation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `Validation` annotation is deprecated.

Second, field names should exactly map the objects in the action. So, the `push` tag is useless, the `User` object is allredy pushed to the value stack by the [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html).

The `validate="true"` informs Struts that you are using a client-side javascript validation.

Make sure you have `s:head` tag and javascript enabled in JSP.

Comment: I didnt know that validate="true" means the validation on the client side. What should i write to make the validation on the server side? Thanks.

Comment: Remove it and it will proceed.

Comment: I've added my web.xml definition. May be there is some problem with it.

Comment: Should I define s:head after deleting validate="true"?

Comment: Yes, you have the problem - `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated.